# Add a row per day or week automatically for multiple years (w/ using script or function ?)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I would like to do is to create a script or with a function that will add automatically the day, the month and the year per row for 4 years for example in order to make a calendar of shooting, pre production and post prod per film. It would be so long to do it manually and add each day per month for 4 or more years. If it's done by a script it would be done instantly and would be possible to update later to add more years.

Example of what I'm looking for

[image]

If it's too complicated per day, I can add per week. Like week 1 January 21, just like in the picture. But I really prefer if that's possible to add a row per day to be the most accurate as possible.

Comment: If you haven't done yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Days for the rest of the year in a column

```
function daysforrestofyear() {
  let days = [];
  let dt = new Date();
  const ldtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear() + 1,0,1).valueOf();
  do {
    days.push([Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MMM/yyyy")]);
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  }while(dt.valueOf() < ldtv)
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,days.length,1).setValues(days);
}
```

| Jun/04/2022 |
| --- |
| Jun/05/2022 |
| Jun/06/2022 |
| Jun/07/2022 |
| Jun/08/2022 |
| Jun/9/2022 |
| Jun/10/2022 |
| Jun/11/2022 |
| Jun/12/2022 |
| Jun/13/2022 |
| Jun/14/2022 |
| Jun/15/2022 |
| Jun/16/2022 |
| Jun/17/2022 |
| Jun/18/2022 |
| Jun/19/2022 |
| Jun/20/2022 |
| Jun/21/2022 |
| Jun/22/2022 |
| Jun/23/2022 |
| Jun/24/2022 |
| Jun/25/2022 |
| Jun/26/2022 |
| Jun/27/2022 |
| Jun/28/2022 |
| Jun/29/2022 |
| Jun/30/2022 |
| Jul/01/2022 |
| Jul/02/2022 |
| Jul/03/2022 |
| Jul/04/2022 |
| Jul/05/2022 |
| Jul/06/2022 |
| Jul/07/2022 |
| Jul/08/2022 |
| Jul/9/2022 |
| Jul/10/2022 |
| Jul/11/2022 |
| Jul/12/2022 |
| Jul/13/2022 |
| Jul/14/2022 |
| Jul/15/2022 |
| Jul/16/2022 |
| Jul/17/2022 |
| Jul/18/2022 |
| Jul/19/2022 |
| Jul/20/2022 |
| Jul/21/2022 |
| Jul/22/2022 |
| Jul/23/2022 |
| Jul/24/2022 |
| Jul/25/2022 |
| Jul/26/2022 |
| Jul/27/2022 |
| Jul/28/2022 |
| Jul/29/2022 |
| Jul/30/2022 |
| Jul/31/2022 |
| Aug/01/2022 |
| Aug/02/2022 |
| Aug/03/2022 |
| Aug/04/2022 |
| Aug/05/2022 |
| Aug/06/2022 |
| Aug/07/2022 |
| Aug/08/2022 |
| Aug/9/2022 |
| Aug/10/2022 |
| Aug/11/2022 |
| Aug/12/2022 |
| Aug/13/2022 |
| Aug/14/2022 |
| Aug/15/2022 |
| Aug/16/2022 |
| Aug/17/2022 |
| Aug/18/2022 |
| Aug/19/2022 |
| Aug/20/2022 |
| Aug/21/2022 |
| Aug/22/2022 |
| Aug/23/2022 |
| Aug/24/2022 |
| Aug/25/2022 |
| Aug/26/2022 |
| Aug/27/2022 |
| Aug/28/2022 |
| Aug/29/2022 |
| Aug/30/2022 |
| Aug/31/2022 |
| Sep/01/2022 |
| Sep/02/2022 |
| Sep/03/2022 |
| Sep/04/2022 |
| Sep/05/2022 |
| Sep/06/2022 |
| Sep/07/2022 |
| Sep/08/2022 |
| Sep/9/2022 |
| Sep/10/2022 |
| Sep/11/2022 |
| Sep/12/2022 |
| Sep/13/2022 |
| Sep/14/2022 |
| Sep/15/2022 |
| Sep/16/2022 |
| Sep/17/2022 |
| Sep/18/2022 |
| Sep/19/2022 |
| Sep/20/2022 |
| Sep/21/2022 |
| Sep/22/2022 |
| Sep/23/2022 |
| Sep/24/2022 |
| Sep/25/2022 |
| Sep/26/2022 |
| Sep/27/2022 |
| Sep/28/2022 |
| Sep/29/2022 |
| Sep/30/2022 |
| Oct/01/2022 |
| Oct/02/2022 |
| Oct/03/2022 |
| Oct/04/2022 |
| Oct/05/2022 |
| Oct/06/2022 |
| Oct/07/2022 |
| Oct/08/2022 |
| Oct/9/2022 |
| Oct/10/2022 |
| Oct/11/2022 |
| Oct/12/2022 |
| Oct/13/2022 |
| Oct/14/2022 |
| Oct/15/2022 |
| Oct/16/2022 |
| Oct/17/2022 |
| Oct/18/2022 |
| Oct/19/2022 |
| Oct/20/2022 |
| Oct/21/2022 |
| Oct/22/2022 |
| Oct/23/2022 |
| Oct/24/2022 |
| Oct/25/2022 |
| Oct/26/2022 |
| Oct/27/2022 |
| Oct/28/2022 |
| Oct/29/2022 |
| Oct/30/2022 |
| Oct/31/2022 |
| Nov/01/2022 |
| Nov/02/2022 |
| Nov/03/2022 |
| Nov/04/2022 |
| Nov/05/2022 |
| Nov/06/2022 |
| Nov/07/2022 |
| Nov/08/2022 |
| Nov/9/2022 |
| Nov/10/2022 |
| Nov/11/2022 |
| Nov/12/2022 |
| Nov/13/2022 |
| Nov/14/2022 |
| Nov/15/2022 |
| Nov/16/2022 |
| Nov/17/2022 |
| Nov/18/2022 |
| Nov/19/2022 |
| Nov/20/2022 |
| Nov/21/2022 |
| Nov/22/2022 |
| Nov/23/2022 |
| Nov/24/2022 |
| Nov/25/2022 |
| Nov/26/2022 |
| Nov/27/2022 |
| Nov/28/2022 |
| Nov/29/2022 |
| Nov/30/2022 |
| Dec/01/2022 |
| Dec/02/2022 |
| Dec/03/2022 |
| Dec/04/2022 |
| Dec/05/2022 |
| Dec/06/2022 |
| Dec/07/2022 |
| Dec/08/2022 |
| Dec/9/2022 |
| Dec/10/2022 |
| Dec/11/2022 |
| Dec/12/2022 |
| Dec/13/2022 |
| Dec/14/2022 |
| Dec/15/2022 |
| Dec/16/2022 |
| Dec/17/2022 |
| Dec/18/2022 |
| Dec/19/2022 |
| Dec/20/2022 |
| Dec/21/2022 |
| Dec/22/2022 |
| Dec/23/2022 |
| Dec/24/2022 |
| Dec/25/2022 |
| Dec/26/2022 |
| Dec/27/2022 |
| Dec/28/2022 |
| Dec/29/2022 |
| Dec/30/2022 |
| Dec/31/2022 |

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly well and it will help me in the future to better understand scripting. It looks simple but I know that it's hard and needs a very huge knowledge in programming and logical.

Comment: No it's actually pretty trivial